# Thinking Sphinx : index translation attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I have a Good model with Globalize3 name tranlation, so:
good.name(:en) return en good name.
good.name(:ru) return rus good name.
I need to sort Good in alphabetical order, depence of current language, so (i think so) i need to make

```
index ... as :en_name
index ... as :ru_name
```

And then search (order : "en_name asc" ) for example.

I have:

```
good.translations
=> [#<Good::Translation id: 5, good_id: 3, locale: "**ru**", name: "**Аурелия** ", description: "\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicin...", created_at: "2012-12-24 13:43:37", updated_at: "2012-12-24 13:43:37">,
 #<Good::Translation id: 6, good_id: 3, locale: **"en"**, name: "**Aurelia**", description: "\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicin...", created_at: "2012-12-24 13:43:37", updated_at: "2012-12-24 13:43:37">]
```

And need do index en_name and ru_name to each good. 
Something like that:

```
indexes "translations(:name) where locale='en'", :as => :en_name, sortable: :insensitive
```

But it not working. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WHERE` clauses shouldn't be a part of field or attribute definitions - as they're within the `SELECT` clause of the underlying SQL query.

You can, however, specify your own `WHERE` conditions easily enough in your index definition:

```
indexes translations.name
# other fields and attributes

where "translations.locale = 'en'"
```